# Updating child table records using one to many bi-directional mapping in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts-1

I am using hibernate one to many bi-directional mapping, While updating record. in child table for **new child** records parent reference variable is storing null in the child table.Please could any one help me out to solve this problem.If its not understandable plz ask me I will post all my entity's relating to this topic. Plz solve from this problem. Thanks in advance.

**MY EDIT CODE:**

```
 LibraryBookForm lb = (LibraryBookForm) form;
            int bookid = lb.getBooklistid();
            System.out.println("bookidbookidbookid" + bookid);
            String[] bar = lb.getBarcode();
            String[] accission = lb.getAccessno();
            System.out.println("accissionaccission" + bar);
            UserEntity msg;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            msg = (UserEntity) session.getAttribute("user");
            int catid = lb.getCategory();
            Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            String d1 = lb.getBilldate();
            java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(d1);
            java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(temp.getTime());
            String d2 = lb.getDateAdded();
            java.util.Date temp1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(d2);
            java.sql.Date submissionDate = new java.sql.Date(temp1.getTime());
            CategoryEntity ce = (CategoryEntity) ses.get(CategoryEntity.class, catid);
            LibraryBookListEntity lbl = (LibraryBookListEntity) ses.load(LibraryBookListEntity.class, bookid);

            Transaction tx = ses.beginTransaction();
            lbl.setEdition(lb.getEdition());
            lbl.setPublisher(lb.getPublisher());
            lbl.setPlace(lb.getPlace());
            lbl.setPage(lb.getPag());
            lbl.setSource(lb.getSource());
            lbl.setBillno(lb.getBillno());
            lbl.setBilldate(date);
            lbl.setPublishedyear(lb.getPublishedyear());
            lbl.setCallno(lb.getCallno());
            lbl.setIsbn(lb.getIsbn());
            lbl.setBooktitle(lb.getBooktitle());
            lbl.setRack(lb.getRack());
            lbl.setAuthor(lb.getAuthor());
            lbl.setPrice(lb.getPrice());
            lbl.setCategoryid(ce);
            lbl.setDateAdded(submissionDate);
            lbl.setTcopies(lb.getTcopies());
            lbl.setAddedBy(msg);
            lbl.setAddedate(new Date());
            lbl.setModifiedBy(null);
            lbl.setModifiedDate(null);
            try {
                java.util.List list = Arrays.asList(bar);
                Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(PageSize.A4));
                File file = new File("d://" + lb.getBooktitle() + ".pdf");
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file, false));
                document.open();
                Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
                Set<LibraryBarCodeEntity> s = new HashSet<LibraryBarCodeEntity>();
                LibraryBarCodeEntity mb = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("inside library model edit");
                    mb = new LibraryBarCodeEntity();
                    System.out.println("bar[i]" + bar[i]);
                    System.out.println("bar[i]" + accission[i]);
                    mb.setBarCode(bar[i]);
                    mb.setAccessno(accission[i]);
                    para.add(new Phrase(new Chunk(BarcodeDao.genarateBarcode(bar[i], writer), 0, 0, true)));
                    para.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
                    para.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
                    s.add(mb);
                }         
                lbl.setChield(s);
                ses.update(lbl);
                tx.commit();
                document.add(para);
                document.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
U forget to set parent reference in the child (In the for loop  mb.setParent(lbl);)

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("inside library model edit");
                mb = new LibraryBarCodeEntity();
                System.out.println("bar[i]" + bar[i]);
                System.out.println("bar[i]" + accission[i]);
                mb.setBarCode(bar[i]);
                mb.setAccessno(accission[i]);
                para.add(new Phrase(new Chunk(BarcodeDao.genarateBarcode(bar[i], writer), 0, 0, true)));
                para.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
                para.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
                mb.setParent(lbl);
                s.add(mb);
            }
```

Comment: thak u so much for helpin me